# How do you launch an access database file from a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have about a dozen users that all access this same Access Database, which is making updates painful since they all have to log out when I update the file.  To solve this, I would like to have them use a simple launcher, like this:

```
DatabaseLauncher.bat

start Z:\AccessDatabases\SharedAccessFile-version1.accde
```

Then, I will update the version in the launcher so that users can close the database and open it at their leisure for the new features.

Running the script produces this error: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Running the command from the command line works perfectly.

Comment: While launching an application directly, I would ideally prefer Windows to choose the app based on the file.  i.e. Not this: "C:\Program Files\...\MSACCESS.EXE" <file-path>

Comment: Dumb question but do you have it open when you run the script? Does anyone else have access to it? Check the Z:\AccessDatabases for a lock file.

Comment: A dozen users access the file and use it at the same time.  This error only occurs when using the `start` command from the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script that solved the problem, along with some enhancements to deal with multiple version of Access on different users machines:

```
if exist "C:\Program Files\Access2007\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE" (
    Start "" "C:\Program Files\Access2007\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE" "Z:\AccessDataBases\SharedAccessFile-version1.accde"
) else (
    if exist "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE" (
        Start "" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE" "Z:\AccessDataBases\SharedAccessFile-version1.accde"
    ) else (
        Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE" "Z:\AccessDataBases\SharedAccessFile-version1.accde"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use in a .vbs script to search the registry for the specified program and, if found run it and if not display a message.  It was patched together from various public sources.

It can be expanded to start a specified database and use parameters such as /x to run a specified macro.

```
dim objShell, WshShell, ProgToFind
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

On Error Resume Next

ProgToFind = "MSACCESS.EXE"

AppPath = WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\" & ProgToFind & "\")

    If Len(AppPath) = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "App Not Found"
        WScript.Quit
        End If

CommandStr = Chr(34) & AppPath & Chr(34)    'Enclose the AppPath in double quotes

objShell.run CommandStr    'Execute the command string
```